# WooCommerce display star rating and count on category / shop page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

How can we display on category page / shop page in one div (to center with `margin:0 auto;`) star rating and number of reviews?

Comment: Hey Alice, can you give the HTML of the div for context? Maybe you can solve this with flexbox

Comment: By default there is no star rating and number of reviews. But i'm adding empty stars and review count with code but it shows 2 separare div
https://codepen.io/alicee11/pen/WNQZVEM

Comment: Can you also show me what the output HTML is of divs?

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you want to center the stars and want the number of reviews on one line?

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I think it's impossible to center that properly. I tried to edit somehow php code but I'm totally I am totally unfamiliar with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this CSS to your site

```
.price-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.star-rating{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.woocommerce-product-rating{
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% + 40px);
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That works to make it in one line. But  it's quite difficult to center it.

Comment: I have edited the solution. Now the price is aligned to the right this is design-wise a better solution than centering the reviews, I think.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't seem to be working well.

I will edit product for a desired design.

Comment: ahhh my fault i forgot position: relative; Updated the answer :)

Comment: Did the solution work for you? I saw that you implemented it on your site

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just what recreated category page. So if you take a look I would be grateful.
At the beggining I didn't consider trying to fix that with css, that's why I didn't make it 'perfectly'.

Comment: No problem I like to help, a lot of people helped me back in the day, when I was figuring everything out. The answers is updated :)

Comment: Updated the css code, and it looks not so well.

Comment: If you want I can add class to count number or change it to span.

Comment: Trail and error XD I have updated the answer

Comment: I suppose it's not possible to center it properly ;/

Comment: Can you draw me an example of how you want it to be? Its hard to guess how you invision it

Comment: I added it in the left sidebar  - "image' with title above 'Desired product design'

https://xn--dlafryzjerw-zeb.pl/kategoria-produktu/clothing/

Comment: Updated it :) hope that this is what your looking for

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much, I suppose it's time to learn flex as it can help me later. Works like a dream.

Comment: Cool! Yes flexbox is great, also worth looking into is CSS grid. Can you mark my answer as complete?